# Was this photo of MH370 captured after disappearance?

Tags: mh370

I found a photo that I am currently trying to verify. It shows MH370, 5 days after disappearance, over Poland.

**Use the link, the image uploaded on StackExchange removes the EXIF**

https://www.kualalumpurpost.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/mh370_file_poland_reuters.jpg

[image: Original image from the link above, image upload on StackExchange removes the EXIF]

The problems with this photo are multiple, I think:

- The Reuters photographer (Tomasz Bartkowiak) states it was captured on February 5, 2014 in the comments of the photo. No other proof the photo was shoot on Feb 5, 2014 (eg. EXIF) is available.
- Photo was first available on the web starting from March 13, 2014. http://www.tineye.com/search/af12a1bd0bf65258348ded2e0194b999d53bebb1/?sort=crawl_date&order=asc
- The photo is available on multiple sites, and when an EXIF is available, it says March 13, 2014 (20:18:41) in Original Date/Time or Digitization Date/Time field.
- I wrote to the photographer and he said he doesn't more own the originals and Reuters manages the rights.
- The photo is not available on the Reuters catalog.
- Searching on Google, I was only able to go the Google cached version of the catalog page, that cornfirms the photo date of March 13, 2014. Link: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:52tiPMKFst8J:pictures.reuters.com/archive/MALAYSIA-AIRLINES--GM1EA3E081M02.html+&cd=1&hl=it&ct=clnk&gl=pt
- I contacted Reuters and I am currently waiting for an answer regarding availability.

Is there any objective evidence as to whether this photo really does show MH370, and really was taken in Poland on Feb 5th 2014, as claimed?

Comment: Even if was taken at that place and time, it could just be another flight. I can't make out any identifying markers. Also, I got a warning when I clicked on that link.

Comment: I voted to close because you didn't provide anyone's claim that the photo was taken on March 13. Is anyone saying this?

Comment: @PointlessSpike It has the same tail number. On March 13 2014 mh370 (tail number 9m-mro) was disappeared by 5 days.

Comment: @Avery Exif from multiple sources. And the cached version of the Reuters Pictures catalog page (that is no more available) says march 13, 2014.. Look above for link.

Comment: @PointlessSpike, the airplane has clear "9M-MRO" markings on the tail and the underside of the left wing.

Comment: As you said yourself the exif data may merely be "digital creation date". And the Reuters byline is for the related article, not the photo (it would surely be newsworthy if the photo were taken March 13). So the photo was taken on Feb 5 and no one is saying otherwise. There is no claim to investigate here.

Comment: Side note: EXIF data, like pretty much everything else about computer files, can be manipulated trivially.  Sometimes even unintentionally.  There are a number of programs specifically to muck with it (for any number of benign reasons); I could make picture appear to be from the future, if you wish?  So what I'm saying is, you can't necessarily trust the EXIF data anyways.

Answer (score 4):

**No**

[Tomasz Bartkowiak](https://www.facebook.com/bartekwrc) is indeed Polish photographer. He indeed does aircraft photography, and he does specialize in high altitude photos.

The picture in question is shown in the local TV [interview with him](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sz7TgNrJPSU). The interview is unrelated to MH370, it's about passion for high altitude airplane photography. The picture is just one of many plane photos shown:
[image]

And indeed the plane in the picture turned out to be the very same aircraft, that was later serving MH370 route. This is believed to be on of the last pictures of the plane. This is the reason why Reuters has bought exclusive rights to the picture (hence it's credited *"Reuters/Tomasz Bartkowiak"* creating misconception that he's *"Reuters photographer"*)

However, he claims to have captured the photo *one month prior* to MH370 disappearance.

[SuperExpress (polish daily) reports](http://www.se.pl/wiadomosci/polska/zaginiony-samolot-malaysia-airlines-nad-jarocinem-wideo_388506.html):

> Zaginiony Boeing 777 najprawdopodobniej zakończył swój lot w Oceanie
>   Indyjskim, nikt nie przeżył katastrofy. Miesiąc przed tragedią
>   fotografowi Tomaszowi Bartkowiakowi udało się zrobić zdjęcia dokładnie
>   temu samolotowi, który przelatywał... nad Jarocinem!

translated:

> Missing Boeing 777 most likely ended its flight in Indian Ocean, no
>   one survived. A month before the tragedy photographer Tomasz
>   Bartkowiak managed to take photo of this very aircraft, which was
>   overflying... Jarocin.

On [his Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/bartekwrc) he's got invitation to exposition of airplane photos, one of which is described as:

> jedno z ostatnich zdjęć samolotu Malaysian Airlines …sławnego
>   zaginionego lotu MH370

translated

> one of the last photos of Malaysian Airlines airplane …the famous
>   missing flight MH370

Again, no claims that it was taken *after* disappearance.

The [Reuters caption of the picture](http://uk.reuters.com/article/uk-malaysia-mh370-africa-idUKKCN0W41U3) is (emphasis mine):

> Boeing 777 Malaysian Airlines Flight MH370 with the registration
>   number 9M-MRO flies over Poland **February 5.**

Comment: Note, that Reuters caption is inaccurate, as it wasn't flight MH370 when it was overflying Poland, but I'm guessing that is just for brevity.

Comment: I posted an answer, inexplicably deleted, which included the up-to-date Reuters caption from the image metadata, which anyone can view. Reuters updated the caption with a "correction", removing the claim that this was flight MH370.

Comment: @user568458: OTOH the question itself make same abbreviation, asking if that's _"photo of MH370"_, rather than asking is that's _"a photo of plane with registration 9M-MRO, which went missing while serving flight MH370"_. I wouldn't attribute any malice to that.

Comment: Not attributing any malice, I posted it as one part of my answer since it explains why Reuters would have removed it from their library (they thought it was MH370, then realised it might not be)